# building a LINQ Expression for unit testing

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I am writing some unit tests for a class and the method I am testing takes in an expression, I am trying to build up and expression and pass it in to the method but I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance,
>   non-static method requires non-null instance. Parameter name: method

```
[TestClass]
public class WhenFilterProvided : FindSubscriptionsForCurrentUserTestBase
{
    bool filterFuncWasCalled;
    private Func<UserSubscription, bool> filterFunc => (userSubscription) =>
    {
        filterFuncWasCalled = true;
        return userSubscription.SubscriptionId == "petrol.prcies.monthly";
    };

    protected override Expression<Func<UserSubscription, bool>> Filter =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<UserSubscription, bool>>(Expression.Call(filterFunc.Method));


    [TestMethod]
    public void CallsDetailsRepository()
    {
        UserDetailsRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.FindAsync("userId", CancellationToken.None), Times.Once);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FilterFuncGetsCalledToFilterSubscriptions()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(filterFuncWasCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Expression.Call,, why not simply call filterFunc() or filterFunc.Invoke()?

Comment: I think you forgot to pass the parameter (userSubscription in the expression) for Expression.Call

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous methods are implemented sometimes [as instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169237/1117815). In your case, the anonymous method must be an instance method because you need to access `this` in order to access `filterFuncWasCalled`.
So you are  trying to invoke an instance method, but you are not passing any instance. You can fix that by passing a constant expression with the instance:

```
Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(filterFunc.Target), filterFunc.Method)
```

But this won't work either, because the method takes a parameter and you are not passing any. Lets use the same one we will use for the lambda expression. This is the full `Filter` property to achieve this:

```
Expression<Func<UserSubscription, bool>> Filter { 
    get {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(UserSubscription));
        var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(filterFunc.Target), filterFunc.Method, param);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<UserSubscription, bool>>(body, param);
    }
}
```